# Can't click on keyboard with PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, popupwindow

My dynamically created PopupWindow containing EditText with the properties:

```
popup.setTouchable(true);  
popup.setFocusable(false);
```

with a forced keyboard to show up:

```
InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
inputMgr.showSoftInput(root, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

shows the keyboard, but doesnt receive any input from the keyboard(ie. pressing keys doesnt add text to the text editor) and the text editor is selected because i can see the cursor  blinking.

I have setFocusable to false because I dont want the PopupWindow to close when I click outside of it.
How can I get the keyboard to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all with the [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) methods.

1. You don't need the `InputMethodManager` to force the soft keyboard
   to show.

   ```
   // Shows soft keyboard if it is not already visible.
   popup.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
   ```
2. Then, you need to allow keyboard interaction.

   ```
   // Allows interaction with the soft keyboard.
   popup.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
   ```
3. Also, you don't need to change the focusability in order to change outside touches behavior.

   ```
   // PopupWindow ignores outside touches.
   popup.setOutsideTouchable(false);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if you setFocusable to false then what's happening is the keyboard is up because you forced it up, but it's not actually talking to that field. You should make your popup field an activity with a theme of Dialog... that will create the same effect and you don't need to mess with focusable.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the dialog from closing when you click outside of it?

Comment: a dialog never closes when you click outside of it. It is only dismissed by either clicking "OK" or by hitting the back button.